# Repeatbox row label not visible until clicked

Tags: smartface.io

I am using this youtube link as a guide

When my repeatbox loads, I see three empty row.  When I click on the row, the text of the label becomes visible.  When I click on a different row, then only the new label is visible.

Has anyone encountered this before?  Is there a recommended font size or row height I should be using?

Comment: You are using both Active and inActive Item, there will be a design problem.
you should check the link http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/repeatbox/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following chances,
 1. Changing background/font color of the label?
 2. Un-check "Enable pull-down to Refresh" & "Enable pull-up to Refresh" options in "Palette". - This is to make confirm that having an issue in repeaterbox rendering rows.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Inactive Item" from "RepeaterBox Edit Mode" from Pallete window. Then add your controls like label, etc.,

[image]

You might be added the controls in Active mode. That is why, controls are not visible till you selected.

For more info: http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/repeatbox/